# Reading Promise result variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I am reading the file data as datastring along with filename

My code will result in correct filename but the filedata is displayed empty {}

The expected output is

```
[{
    filename: "name1.txt",
    filedata: "data:text/plain;base64,VGhpc.."
}, {
    filename: "name2.txt",
    filedata: "data:text/plain;base64,VGhpc.."
}]
```

My code is

```js
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
      resolve(fr.result);
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
      reject(fr);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
  });
}

// Handle multiple fileuploads
function uploadForm() {
  let files = $('#file')[0].files // ev.currentTarget.files;
  let readers = [];
  if (!files.length) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    readers.push({
      "filedata": readFile(files[i]),
      "filename": files[i].name
    });
  }
  Promise.all(readers).then((values) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
    return
  });
}

function showMessage(e) {
  $('#progress').html(e);
  $('#file').val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
      <td>Select File:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="file" type="file" value="" accept=".csv,.xlsx,.docx,.rtf,.pdf,.pptx,.txt" multiple>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button onclick="uploadForm();" id="upload">Upload</button>&emsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="progress"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would repair this by just pushing the promises into an array, so you can easily await them all with `Promise.all`.  Then when you get your result array, map it to an array of `{ filedata, filename }` objects.

Here's the different part:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    readers.push(readFile(files[i]));
  }
  Promise.all(readers).then((values) => {
    const result = values.map((filedata,i) => ({
      filedata,
      filename: files[i].name
     }));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    return
  });
```

#### Your whole example, repaired.

```js
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
      resolve(fr.result);
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
      reject(fr);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
  });
}

// Handle multiple fileuploads
function uploadForm() {
  let files = $('#file')[0].files // ev.currentTarget.files;
  let readers = [];
  if (!files.length) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    readers.push(readFile(files[i]));
  }
  Promise.all(readers).then((values) => {
    const result = values.map((filedata,i) => ({
      filedata,
      filename: files[i].name
     }));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    return
  });
}

function showMessage(e) {
  $('#progress').html(e);
  $('#file').val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
      <td>Select File:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="file" type="file" value="" accept=".csv,.xlsx,.docx,.rtf,.pdf,.pptx,.txt" multiple>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button onclick="uploadForm();" id="upload">Upload</button>&emsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="progress"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `readers` can be initialized in one line with: `let readers = files.map(readFile)`

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `Promise.all()` should be an array of promises. `readers` is an array of ordinary objects, the promises are in the `filedata` properties. You're just logging those objects, not the result of the promises.

Extract the `filedata` properties when calling `Promise.all()`.

Then in the `Promise.all()` callback, you can loop over all the results, and log them along with the corresponding filename from `readers`.

```js
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
      resolve(fr.result);
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
      reject(fr);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
  });
}

// Handle multiple fileuploads
function uploadForm() {
  let files = $('#file')[0].files // ev.currentTarget.files;
  let readers = [];
  if (!files.length) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    readers.push({
      "filedata": readFile(files[i]),
      "filename": files[i].name
    });
  }
  Promise.all(readers.map(r => r.filedata)).then((values) => {
    values.forEach((value, i) => console.log(readers[i].filename, JSON.stringify(value)))
  });
}

function showMessage(e) {
  $('#progress').html(e);
  $('#file').val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
      <td>Select File:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="file" type="file" value="" accept=".csv,.xlsx,.docx,.rtf,.pdf,.pptx,.txt" multiple>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button onclick="uploadForm();" id="upload">Upload</button>&emsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="progress"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```